# Generating Site maps in java and making them available publicly

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm using a java framework, Tapestry5. I have millions of pages and I'd like to generate my sitemaps with a nightly cron job rather than dynamically generate them on the fly. The problem I'm facing is I don't seem to know how to place the xml sitemaps dynamically in a directory that can be read publicly. Currently I have a manually written xml sitemap that points to dynamically written ones. The manually written sitemap is placed in the Web Pages / webapp directory along side the robots.txt file. How do I place a file there with java?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to write to areas within your WAR directory. Fortunately, all the popular web and app servers (except perhaps some cloud hosting environments like Google App Engine) have the ability to configure an arbitrary directory on the file system as the path corresponding to particular URL patterns. This gives you the freedom to put the sitemap files anywhere you want.

Comment: Hi bob, I stumbled on the following libarary which appears to be able to handle everything I need to do. https://code.google.com/p/sitemapgen4j/ However I'm facing the same issue with the base url, where would you recommend setting the base URL? I'm using maven with the following foller structure /src/main/webapp. I still don't know a lot about writing to these files. I do use aws, so I wonder if writing to an S3 server would be better?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used AWS or S3 for a long time, but I suppose an S3 server might be an option. Read the docs to be sure. I think all you need is a directory you can write to that a web server or app server is configured to read from.